# Clearing Text on Certain Dates in VB

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so I am working on the very last part of my program and I am wondering if this is possible in VB and how to do it. I was thinking it was probably going to turn into a big If Statement, but I am not sure on the code to be exact.

Basically what I am trying to do is have my program write a new line of text into a .txt file once a day, I got that going good, but now what I want the program to do is to clear the entire .txt file at the start of each month, while also writing to the .txt file after the clear on the same day.

Is this possible? If so, could I get some help on this? Thank you!

Comment: Does the program need to know if it already ran today?

Comment: It does not. Its just a basic program that scrapes a quote from a website once run and saves to a .txt file. That file is then called to display the accumulated text in new lines. I just want it to clear automatically at the start of the month, right before it writes the new quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that it's as simple as this:

```
If Date.Now.Date.Day = 1 Then
    File.Create(Path).Close() ' replace with your path to the file
End If
```

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get home. If it works, you saved me from 3 days of pain. XD